# Is a raid container always inactive?

Tags: linux, raid

I am facing a monitoring issue. Our monitoring alerts if a raid device is reported as "inactive" in /proc/mdstat. The output on our server looks like this:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : active raid1 sdb[1] sda[0]
      234427392 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : inactive sdb[1](S) sda[0](S)
      6306 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

As you can see there is an IMSM container from which the actual raid is build. This container is always "inactive".
My question is: Are IMSM containers (or raid containers in general) always "inactive"?

Btw: I have no clue why we are even using IMSM fakeraids at all.

Thank you for your help!

Take care,
Alex